# How to copy an external file into the current running jar?

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I want to edit a configuration file located in the current running jar.
Is there a way that allows modify directly this file or copy it from external?

Comment: You can't. The jar files are read-only at runtime. Configuration files should be stored externally, though you may have a default file in the jar, to use if no external file is specified, and/or to use to apply the values not defined in the external file.

Comment: thank you  Andreas for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the `jar` being run at `runtime` like [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) suggested in the comments. I'll just put in a possible alternative to why you might need this in here, so this question doesn't show up in unanswered page.

**Why?**

> > When a `jar` is running (that is, it is being used by JVM), the file (archive >>file) is **locked** by the Operating System. When any file is locked (or marked as locked) it cannot be changed, in other words it is as good as a **read-only** file.

**Why you might be in need of doing this.**

> > Reason why usually people try to write into `jar` is that, they want a file which they want to use with absolute/relative path (with reference to `jar` file).

**What option do we have in this case?**

> > So, if this is your issue, you can make a directory in the `jar`'s location and use it.
> >
> > If your `jar` is at `C:\Users\<Something>\Desktop\testDir\`, then you create a directory 'conf' (`C:\Users\<Something>\Desktop\testDir\conf\`) in this place. You can write/create files in this directory and reference them from your code easily (with reference to the current working directory's path).